# FlatList can't scroll and not update the item after add or edit

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in react native.
I have created the display and contain the FlatList. My FlatList can't scroll through the items and it can't update the list items after I add or edit the item but it can update after I refresh the the app.

This is my **list.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
export default function MovieList(props) {
    const [movies,setMovies] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`http://192.168.1.250:8000/api/movies/`,{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`token 91f29b5f051fef8a1c6ab2779ed0410be37ceb48`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(jsonRes => setMovies(jsonRes))
        .catch(error=>console.log(error));
    },[])
    const movieclicked = (movie) =>{
      props.navigation.navigate("Detail",{movie:movie,title:movie.title})
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/killer-queen.png')}
            style={{ width:'100%', height:135, paddingTop:30 }}
            resizeMode= 'contain'
            />
        <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        data={movies}
        extraData={movies}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => movieclicked(item)}>
              <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>   
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
        />
        </View>
    );
}
MovieList.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  title :'List of Movies',
  headerStyle : {
    backgroundColor:'orange',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerTitleStyle : {
    fontWeight : 'bold',
    fontSize : 20,
  },
  headerRight: () => (
   <Button title='Add New' color='orange' onPress={()=>screenProps.navigation.navigate('Edit',{movie:{title:'',description:''}})} />
  ),
})
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#282c35',
  },
  item:{
    flex:1,
    padding:10,
    height:50,
    backgroundColor:'#282c35',
  },
  itemText:{
    color:'#fff',
    fontSize:20
  }
});
```

This is my **edit.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,TextInput } from 'react-native';



export default function Edit(props) {

  const movie = props.navigation.getParam('movie',null)
  const [title,setTitle] = useState(movie.title)
  const [description,setDescription] = useState(movie.description)
  const saveMovie = () => {
    if (movie.id) {
      fetch(`http://192.168.1.250:8000/api/movies/${movie.id}/`,{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`token 91f29b5f051fef8a1c6ab2779ed0410be37ceb48`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ title: title, description: description})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(movie => {
          props.navigation.navigate("Detail",{movie:movie,title:movie.title})
        })
        .catch(error=>console.log(error));

    } else {
      fetch(`http://192.168.1.250:8000/api/movies/`,{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`token 91f29b5f051fef8a1c6ab2779ed0410be37ceb48`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ title: title, description: description})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(movie => {

          props.navigation.navigate("MovieList")
        })
        .catch(error=>console.log(error));
    }
    
     
  };
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text style={styles.label}>Title</Text>
           <TextInput
            style = {styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Input the movie title.'
            onChangeText = {text=>setTitle(text)}
            value={title}
           />
           <Text style={styles.label}>Description</Text>
           <TextInput
            style = {styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Input the movie description.'
            onChangeText = {text=>setDescription(text)}
            value={description}
           />
           <Button onPress={() => saveMovie()} title={movie.id?"Edit":"Add"}/>
      </View>
    );
}

Edit.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  title : screenProps.navigation.getParam('title'),
  headerStyle : {
    backgroundColor:'orange',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerTitleStyle : {
    fontWeight : 'bold',
    fontSize : 20,
  },
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#282c35',
    padding:10,
  },
  label:{
    color:'#fff',
    fontSize:24,
    padding:10,
  },
  input:{
    fontSize:24,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding:10,
    margin:10
  }
});
```

Please help me to resolve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you do in `AddNew` ? ...plz include related code...

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion for your current logic ...**

is to use `refreshStamp` as a trigger for your `MoviesList` to **re-fetch** your list... cause you're currently fetching movies-list when on `componentDidMount` only, by passing `[]` to your `useEffect-deps param` ... that's why you see the update only after reloading-app, cause you're forcing remount of your component...

```
 /** In your Edit screen */
  navigation.navigate('MovieList', { refreshStamp: Date.now() });

  /** In MoviesList */
  const refreshStamp = props.route.params?.refreshStamp;
  useEffect(() => {
    /** fetch your movies list here */
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refreshStamp) {
      /** fetch your movies list here */
    }
  }, [refreshStamp]);
```

**Better Approach**

Use **redux-actions** to handle your fetch-ops... I mean to have a redux-action to handle **edit||add**, which should re-fetch `movies-list` on-success...